# Why can I still access array automatic allocated in function after return?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, stack

I tried to run this simple code and was expecting it to crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void setPtrOnTempData(char **ptr) {
    char str[] = "AAAA";
    *ptr = str;
}

int main() {
    char temp[] = "Paras";
    temp[3] = 'F';

    char *ptr = temp;
    ptr++;
    ptr[3] = 'F';
    printf("%s", ptr);  // prints "arFF"

    setPtrOnTempData(&ptr);

    ptr[0] = 'F';
    printf("%s", ptr);  // prints "FAAA"

    return 0;
}
```

The reasons why I thought so, if I'm not wrong:

1. Elements of automatic allocated array are all allocated in stack, so after function return I lost control of it.
2. Array variable is address of base element of this array in stack, so assignment of pointer passed as argument will point to that lost position in stack.

But result is that I still have access to some memory, where array was allocated and I'm still able to change data of this array.

Why is that so, and where my view is wrong? Thanks!!

UPD_1: I'm sorry for my inaccuracy, there was "statically" instead of "automatic" in the title at first.

UPD_2: I also tried to fill stack with some new data, for example, allocate in another function new array for 10 char elements, and call this function, thought maybe it will refresh data under `ptr` address, that was used by `setPtrOnTempData` earlier, but result is the same, data under `ptr` is not changed after it. Why is that so, if stack has grown and have been refreshed?

Comment: Welcome to the land of [undefined-behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen.

Comment: Statically allocated means *not* on the stack.  In fact, that's exactly what the `static` keyword (which you haven't used) does.  You're confusing the term "static" with the term "automatic".

Comment: Undefined behavior means you are not justified in having *any* particular expectation. Not even "it will crash".

Comment: @wohlstad: I also tried to fill stack with some new data, for example, allocate in another function new array for 10 char elements, and call this function, thought maybe it will refresh data under ptr address, that was used by setPtrOnTempData earlier, but result is the same, data under ptr is not changed after it.

Comment: @Jr_vv - Local data on the stack will go away after the function has returned. Nothing says that it has to go away *immediately*. The rules do say that the code is not allowed to read it anymore, so there is no valid way to detect that.

Comment: @TomKarzes: static and heap allocation are standard terms for situation I describe, a lot of textbooks and articles use it.

Comment: Here is the same question, but for C++, with the best answer ever: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/17398063)

Comment: @BoP: Thx you a lot!! Now it's more clear to me

Comment: @Jr_vv Heap allocation refers to dynamically allocated memory. Static storage refers to permanent storage that does not disappear after a function returns.  You're using the term incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

First, as a point of clarification, the array `str` in `setPtrOnTempData` is not statically allocated.  Variables that are statically allocated, or more accurately those with *static storage duration* (i.e. with the `static` keyword or at file scope) have full program lifetime.  What you have is a variable with *automatic storage duration* whose lifetime ends when `setPtrOnTempData` returns.

When you access the memory of a variable whose lifetime has ended, as you've done here, it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

With undefined behavior, there is no guarantee what your code will do.  It might crash, it might exhibit strange behavior, or (as in your case) it might appear to work properly.  Also, the way undefined behavior manifests itself can change with a seemingly unrelated change to your code, such as adding an unused variable or a call to `printf` for debugging.

Just because your code *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Answer (score 0):

Not a C developer. But I think the issue is in your code, the "setPtrOnTempData" function assigns a local array's address to a pointer in the main function. But then the local array str[] gets deallocated when the function returns.

You're creating a local array str[] within the setPtrOnTempData function. But this array's scope is only within the function. So when you assign *ptr = str, you're assigning the address of the local array str to ptr, which points to ptr in main. But when it gets deallocated when returning
it might seem it's working but it accesses invalid memory resulting in this weird scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title of the question: yes, you can.

```
void setPtrOnTempData(char **ptr) {
    /*ADDED>>>*/ static /*<<<ADDED*/ char str[] = "AAAA";
    *ptr = str; // ✓
}
//...
setPtrOnTempData(&ptr); 
ptr[0] = 'F'; //✓
//...
```

A `static` object has `static` lifetime duration, and you can access it by pointer even where it's not accessible by name (<=> is out of scope).

But you're missing the `static` keyword in your code and without it, you're accessing a variable whose lifetime has ended, which is undefined behavior.